# Convert Minimap render texture to 3d space position

Tags: unity, c#, camera, raycasting, minimap

I am using **Render Texture** to make a Mini Map it is working fine. Now I want world space position from render texture click point.

**Is there any way available that I get the world space position from the render texture's specific click point?**

If I click somewhere in render texture then, how can I get that point in 3D world space?

For example, I click a car object on render texture How can I highlight or get it in 3D world space.?

Update: Actual Scenario is:

1. One Main Camera Rendering the Scene.
2. NGUI Camera Rendering the GUI.
3. That GUI contains the Render Texture(minimap) which rendering the
   scene on texture using GUI Camera.

Now how can I get 3D position from 2D render texture!

Comment: i didnt get what you want to say

Comment: As always, It kind of depends..
I'll have to assume a lot about how your minimap system works I think. 

If you have a 2d minimap of 100X100 pixels which you view top dowwn. Your world is 1km by 1km then each pixel on your minimap is 10m world units.

so say you click the minimaps middle pixel ( 50,50 ). multiply the pixel coord by the 10m world units gives you 500m, 500m.

So thats 500m in x, 500m in z in world units.

Comment: my godness what a calculation you have mention! is this real and applicable???

Comment: Yes and yes. You'll have to elaborate

Comment: Dont you think that it is too hard and it can cause inaccurate results as well. I say u mention 20+ experirence in your profile! did you ever make a minimap where you go minimap to 3d?

Comment: Then define smaller real area size /pixelCount ratio

Comment: Yes, i've done so many times. Essentially i'm trying to describe to you a simple transformation. Like I say, i'm assuming a lot you haven't provided that much detail. I really dont understand what it is that you don't understand even :(

Comment: Can you not just use the guicameras transform and do viewport to world or screen to world?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of an easy way of doing this. The way I'd do this is the following:

- Determine XY position of click on texture (x = 0..1, y = 0..1) How to do this depends on where you use it, but will likely require raycasting.
- Go to the camera that sends the image to the texture.

**Assuming the camera uses perspective projection:**

- Calculate the 3D position on the camera's far plane that is at position x and y (xy was derived earlier from the texture)
- Do a raycast from the camera's position to this calculated position on the far plane.
- The first position it hits (in 3D) is the 3D position of what was clicked on. If nothing is hit, then it's the position on the far plane.

**Assuming the camera uses orthogonal projection:**

- Determine XYZ position of point on the near plane that is at the XY position, determined from the template
- Determine XYZ position of point on the far plane that is at the XY position, determined from the template
- Do a raycast from the position on the near plane to the one on the far plane.
- The first position it hits (in 3D) is the 3D position of what was clicked on. If nothing is hit, then it's the position on the far plane.

Now determining all of this requires some knowledge of vector math. I'm however not aware of any simpler way of doing it, at least if you want to use the Rendered Texture. It may be easier to do if you simply overlay the camera's output on the main viewport (by setting Viewport Rect parameters on the minimap camera)